# How do I make the play button have a border which progresses as time goes?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a program which will play 30 seconds of a song stored in parse. Currently I can play the song when the button is clicked, but I want the border to show the progress of the 30 sec. i.e 15 sec into the preview of the song, the border will be halfway, 30 sec the border will be complete. How would I do this? Below is my code to create the button.

```
let playButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    let imageret = "playbutton"
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: imageret), forState: .Normal)
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(230, 20, 100, 100)
    playButton.addTarget(self,action: "playit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is there something happening or not happening that shouldn't/should with the code you have written? SO is a great resource for getting questions answered, but we should be careful not to seek outsourcing the actual work of your project.

Comment: Just advice on how do go about doing this will suffice, I don't need someone to actually write the code for me. I just don't know where to start.

Comment: can you provide a sketch of the result you want ?

Comment: Something like these, but as the time goes on the progress bar will also move. https://www.google.com/search?q=circular+progress+bar+time&safe=strict&espv=2&biw=1272&bih=654&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIrLmOhPL5yAIVStBjCh1dXAKk#safe=strict&tbm=isch&q=circular+progress+bar+swift&imgrc=1MjVOzmrjP-1pM%3A

Comment: it's very simple. Create a view ( say "playView") with a border having width as you wish. Now add tap gesture on playView. On taping of playView start playing & fill border color gradually from calculation.

Comment: This is all I have and when I click the play button it will just add a red circle to the view, but I want it to animate as in fill the circle as time goes, how would I do that? http://puu.sh/lbcYh/c1102efaf7.png